# Laravel: How can I divide different types of the same model in my view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an `Athlete` model, and an `Evaluation` model.

**Athlete**

```
/**
 * An athlete has an evaluation.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function evaluation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Evaluation');
}
```

**Evaluation**

```
/**
 * An evaluation belongs to an athlete.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function athlete()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Athlete');
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param Athlete $athlete
 * @return $this
 */
public function show(Athlete $athlete)
{
    return view('athletes.show')->with(compact('athlete'));
}
```

Within each `Evaluation` I have a `status` column which is an `enum`.

```
draft
published
revision
```

An athlete can only have 1 evaluation that is published at any given time.
An athlete can only have 1 evaluation draft at any given time.

An athlete can have many revisions. A revision is just an archived version of the previous evaluation when a new one is saved.

I'm not sure how to separate out the versions in my view. For example, I only want the `published` version to populate a textarea.

```
<textarea class="form-control evaluation" rows="3" cols="5" id="evaluation" name="comments">
    {{ $athlete->evaluation->comments ?? '' }}
</textarea>
```

So I think I need something like:

```
{{ $athlete->evaluation->comments::where('status', 'published')->first() ?? '' }}
```

But I know that is incorrect.

The same could be said for showing the revisions in a list somewhere on my page.

```
@foreach($athlete->evaluation->comments::where('status', 'revision')...
```

Or are these objects I need to separately set up in my controller as `evaluation`, `drafts`, `revisions`?

Then in my controller have:

```
return view('athletes.show')->with(compact('athlete', 'evaluation', 'drafts', 'revisions'));
```

That seems like a waste of resources though since I've already got everything I need.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: You could abstract your logic to a repository pattern. So you write something like `$athlete->publishedEvaluation`. See: https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ However, as I type, I realized it might be an overkill, you could use query scope: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, you have two options. Here's a simple one:

```
// Athlete.php
// An athlete actually has many evaluations, but with different statuses

public function evaluations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Evaluation');
}


public function getPublishedEvaluationAttribute()
{
    return $this->evaluations->first(function ($evaluation) {
        return $evaluation->status === 'published';
    });
}
```

Then, on your view:

```
{{ $athlete->evaluations->where('status', 'published')->first()->comments ?? '' }}
```

Or, using the accessor we just created:

```
{{ $athlete->publishedEvaluation->comments ?? '' }}
```

Alternatively, you can chain you relationship query to get what you want straight from the database and not iterate to check the status. This means more queries when you want more than one status on your view, but it might make sense in other parts of your application.

```
// Athlete.php

public function evaluations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Evaluation');
}


public function publishedEvaluations()
{
    return $this->evaluations()->where('status', 'published');
}
```

The problem with this approach is that even though you know you only have one, you have to return a relationship in your method, otherwise Laravel will throw an Exception. Which means that in your view you'd have to write something like:

```
{{ $athlete->publishedEvaluations->first()->comments ?? '' }}
```

Obviously they are all simplifications (I'd strongly advise to check for the existence of an evaluation before trying to access the `comments` attribute), but hopefully will lead you on the path you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is exactly the shove I needed.